# set LinearLayout on center android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have one LinearLayout in which there are two components one is SquareLayout and second one is RecyclerView, i want SquareLayout in center of the screen and RecyclerView in bottom of the screen , don't know why but gravity not work for set it. i am new in android i hope my question is clear. Here is my .xml file..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <com.example.layouts.SquareLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSelectedLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        ></com.example.layouts.SquareLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/rvImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: LinearLayout can't do that i think, but RelativeLayout can

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, It will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout for do that.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.gridcollagelayouts.SquareLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSelectedLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:centerInParent="true" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:below="@+id/llSelectedLayout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: might wanna remove the xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" and xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" from the Recyclerview in the answer